# Mongo gem how to db.currentOp

Tags: ruby, mongodb

How can I do `db.currentOp()` via the ruby Mongo gem?
Cant seem to find that in the gem api and documentation
Is it supported? 
if not Is there a gem that does support that?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the definition of `currentOp` in the JS console, it looks very internal to me.

```
> db.currentOp
function ( arg ){
    var q = {}
    if ( arg ) {
        if ( typeof( arg ) == "object" )
            Object.extend( q , arg );
        else if ( arg )
            q["$all"] = true;
    }
    return this.$cmd.sys.inprog.findOne( q );
}
```

Besides, official mongo ruby driver doesn't contain "currentOp", "current_op", "inprog" or any other similar term. Based on this I must conclude that it's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can send manual commands to the driver using the `command` call:

```
conn.command(currentOp: 1)
```

Should do that for you.